# Как из RGB получить число в HEX и перевести его в десятичную?

Tags: c++, экран, скриншот, rgb

Имеется вот такой вот код:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
/* Globals */
int ScreenX = 0;
int ScreenY = 0;
BYTE* ScreenData = 0;

void ScreenCap()
{
    HDC hScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    ScreenX = GetDeviceCaps(hScreen, HORZRES);
    ScreenY = GetDeviceCaps(hScreen, VERTRES);

    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreen);
    HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreen, ScreenX, ScreenY);
    HGDIOBJ hOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, ScreenX, ScreenY, hScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hOld);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.biWidth = ScreenX;
    bmi.biHeight = -ScreenY;
    bmi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.biSizeImage = 0;// 3 * ScreenX * ScreenY;

    if (ScreenData)
        free(ScreenData);
    ScreenData = (BYTE*)malloc(4 * ScreenX * ScreenY);

    GetDIBits(hdcMem, hBitmap, 0, ScreenY, ScreenData, (BITMAPINFO*)&bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hScreen);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}

inline int PosB(int x, int y)
{
    return ScreenData[4 * ((y * ScreenX) + x)];
}

inline int PosG(int x, int y)
{
    return ScreenData[4 * ((y * ScreenX) + x) + 1];
}

inline int PosR(int x, int y)
{
    return ScreenData[4 * ((y * ScreenX) + x) + 2];
}

bool ButtonPress(int Key)
{
    bool button_pressed = false;

    while (GetAsyncKeyState(Key))
        button_pressed = true;

    return button_pressed;
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (ButtonPress(VK_SPACE))
        {

            // Print out current cursor position
            POINT p;
            GetCursorPos(&p);
            printf("X:%d Y:%d \n", p.x, p.y);
            // Print out RGB value at that position
            std::cout << "Bitmap: r: " << PosR(p.x, p.y) << " g: " << PosG(p.x, p.y) << " b: " << PosB(p.x, p.y) << "\n";

        }
        else if (ButtonPress(VK_ESCAPE))
        {
            printf("Quit\n");
            break;
        }
        else if (ButtonPress(VK_SHIFT))
        {
            ScreenCap();
            printf("Captured\n");
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

На Shift делается скриншот экрана, на SPACE анализ пикселя, где находится мышка. На ESC завершение .exe.
Однако меня не устраивает RGB. По какой-то причине R вызывает исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
Мне RGB вообще не нужен, только мешает, по этому я перевожу его в 1 число так:

```
C = PosR(i, j) * 1000000 + PosG(i, j) * 1000 + PosB(i, j);
```

Скорее всего это и вызывает исключение. Но что можно сделать, чтобы получать цвет в HEX? Однако не просто HEX, а ещё и вернуть обратно в десятичное число. Вот как в этом коде:

```
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, 100, 100);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    cout << color;
```

Жёлтый цвет в 2 вариантах:
R = 255, G = 255, B = 0
HEX: 65535
Или например белый:
R = 255, G = 255, B = 255
HEX: 16777215
Я думаю, что можно изменить что-то в BITMAP, однако что я там не тыкал, ничего не получилось. Из 3 массивов не хотелось бы переводить, не рационально.

Comment: Гм... (red*256+green)*256+blue вас устроит? А еще лучше — просто читайте его как `unsigned int` прямо из `ScreenData[4 * ((y * ScreenX) + x)]`, а не делите по байтам...

Comment: Странно, на выводе мне показывается:
R = 255
G = 255
B = 0,

`unsigned int B = ScreenData[4 * ((p.y * ScreenX) + p.x)]; `
это выдаёт 0,

(red*256+green)*256+blue умножение 1 строкой = 0,

умножение через разные строки = 16711935 (это НЕ верное число)

Comment: @Harry но ведь если цвет будет R = 255, G = 0, B = 0, и вставить его в формулу (red*256+green)*256+blue, тогда на выходе будет 65280, но это не правильно! На выходе должно быть 255 (красный).

Comment: Пардон, поменять местами — (blue*256+green)*256+red

Comment: @Harry действительно работает, при этом я нашёл 2 формулу: R+255*G+G+65535*B+B. Но вы говорили про ScreenData, можете пожалуйста объяснить, что мне необходимо сделать? Можно будет даже засчитать за ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

за формулу спасибо Harry, работает прекрасно:
(blue*256+green)*256+red

Я вынес это в отдельную функцию:

```
int GETSCREEN(int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2)
{
    ScreenCap();
    for (int j = Y1; j < Y2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = X1; i < X2; i++)
        {
            Screen[i][j] = ((PosB(i, j)) * 256 + (PosG(i, j))) * 256 + (PosR(i, j));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

X1, Y1 и X2, Y2 - координаты области которую необходимо получить в массив.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]